# Swift: Creating Edges Around Button And Adding Text

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to turn my rectangular button into a sort of oval by getting edges on it.  Is there anyway to do this programatically through swift?

Also, is there any way to add a string or text to the button?  I appreciate it, still getting used to programming swift.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Quartzcore and layer property to achieve this. Eg -

```
import QuartzCore

let MyView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 55))
MyView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
MyView.clipsToBounds = true
```

You can add this in your ViewDidLoad function. Try it

Comment: Not necessary to import `QuartzCore` when `UIKit` is already included.